# LibGDX: Fix table background drawable

Tags: java, libgdx, alignment, drawable, scene2d

I have a little problem with the Table. When I execute this:

```
toolBar = new Table(Assets.instance.bg_skin);
toolBar.setBackground("bg_table");
toolBar.setFillParent(true);
toolBar.align(Align.top);
```

I get the added actors align to the topcenter but the background drawable fills the whole screen.

My goal is to get a toolbar on top

Answer (score 0):

After you add all your actors, try with this:

```
table.add().expand().fill();
```

To add an empty cell that will occupy the rest of the screen space.

I guess, but not to sure, you should remove `toolBar.align(Align.top);` too.

Comment: and how can i align the Table on the top center? Edit if I set FillParrent to false my Table gets drawn on the bottom conner.

Comment: Well found a awser: I have to use a VerticalGroup. Because alignment does only happen in the Actor and not actor to parrent like I tought. (Javadoc does explain it). The background drawable uses the maxBounds. Solution: Add the Table to the VerticalGroup, fill the VerticalGroup and add it to the Stage.